# React multidimensonal array filter/find

Tags: reactjs, react-native, multidimensional-array, filter

I have a multidimensional array (list of matchs with players) and i need to filter this array to only get unique player object.

The following code works but the result i expected is different.

```
Const aPlayer=matchs
  .filter(match => match.players.find(player => player.id     
 ===id))
```

The variable aPlayer contains all matchs for this player.

But i only need player object data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your data structured like this:

```
Matches: List<Match>
Match:   {
    ...,
    players: List<Player>
}
Player: {
   id: Index,
   ...
}
```

If so, you can do it like this:

```
// still contains duplicates, but that's not the issue here
const allPlayers = matchs
    .map(x => x.players)
    .reduce(x => (dest, val) => dest.concat(val), []);

const player = allPlayers.find(x => x.id === id);
```

Comment: does not work, console.log(allPLayers)= "function(dest,val) { return dest.concat(val);}"

Comment: What exactly does not work and what's the error/the result?

Comment: Const allPlayers=matchs
  .filter(match => match.players.find(player => player.id     
 ===id)) follow by const player = allPlayers.find(x => x.id === id); do the job , thanks